# html select list selected item and maximum value can be selected

Tags: html, selectlist

HELLO,
i have an html select list, and i want: the selected number to be a given value `$content->number`, and the maximum value to be  `$content->product_type->stock_2` if it is less than 5, or 5 if it is greater than 5.

now i have:

```
<select class="number" name="number">
    <? $max = $content->product_type->stock_2 > 5 ? 5 : $content->product_type->sale_stock; ?>
        <option value="<?= $content->number ?>"><?= $content->number; ?> </option>                      
    <? for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++):?>                        
        <option <?php if($content->product_type->stock_2 == $i) echo 'selected="selected"' ;?> value="<?= $i ?>"><?= $i; ?></option>            
    <? endfor; ?>
</select>
```

but it shows me twice the selected value `$content->number`. i'm sure i am mistaking somewhere.

Any suggestions?
thank you!

Comment: Dana is your problem with this `<? $max = $content->product_type->stock_2 > 5 ? 5 : $content->product_type->sale_stock; ?>` I cannot seem to understand the whole question. you want max to be 5 if this `$content->product_type->stock_2 > 5` is true and you want it to be this `$content->product_type->sale_stock` if `$content->product_type->stock_2 > 5` is false, right?

Comment: exactly:) this is what i want

Comment: :) but in your question you say **the maximum value to be $content->product_type->stock_2 if it is less than 5** I mean you need to write a 2 at the end of `<? $max = $content->product_type->stock_2 > 5 ? 5 : $content->product_type->sale_stock; ?>` don't you?

Comment: oh, ok, i have a little issue there:) but what i want: as you can see, my solution for setting the default selected value is to 'hardcode' it in the select list as the first element. bUT I will have this element twice in my list, because i will also have it in the interval between 1 and the maximum, if the max in not equal to one. this is what i want to get rid of (that duplication of this value). thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether I correct understood what you want to do, but try this:

```
<select class="number" name="number">
    <? $max = $content->product_type->stock_2 > 5 ? 5 : $content->product_type->sale_stock; ?>
        <option value="<?= $content->number ?>"><?= $content->number; ?> </option>     
    <? for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++):?>
        <? if ($i != $content->number): ?>                        
            <option <?php if($content->product_type->stock_2 == $i) echo 'selected="selected"' ;?> value="<?= $i ?>"><?= $i; ?></option> 
        <? endif; ?>           
    <? endfor; ?>
</select>
```